# share data status on different instances of WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have two servers(and could be more later) with a WCF service, both behind a load balancer. The client application, in multiple IS servers(also loadbalanced), call the WCF to do some action, lets say a Save.
The same data, lets say Client information, could be opened by several users at same time.
The Save action can be, then, be executed from several users at the same time, and the call will go to different WCF servers.

I want that when a user call Save from UI, and there is already a Save in progress from another UI over the same Client data, then the second user be alerted about it.
For that, all WCF instances should know about actions been executed in other instances.

How can I synchronize data status between all WCF server instances then ?
I dont want to share the data, just some status of the data(opened, save in progress, something like that)

please advice, thanks,

I'm working with c#/.NET4

Added: WCF is actually hosted inside a windows service.

Comment: Can you post code samples?  This question is a bit too broad, parts of the problem like making sure it's only saved once could be solved using asynchronous processes maybe using the Command Pattern and a Message Bus..

Comment: well I think code sample is not important here, the question is more on the architecture to setup. Message Bus was already discussed, seems other team members prefer to avoid a middleware layer, we are looking for other possible ways.

Comment: You could use some sort of centralised locking system and something like SignalR to alert other viewers of the same data being changed/saved.

Comment: SignalR already discussed as notification mechanism. But still not clear in synchronization part.

Comment: You might need to provide some code samples or more information for that part.  I'm not sure there's enough to go on, as by default WCF services should be stateless.

Comment: well I have no code for this, there is nothing done yet. I'm thinking to use just some table in DB to keep track of current status of Client data access... dont know impact about performance yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is one of resource management.

You are trying to resolve a way how you can get your service clients to somehow all know about what open handles each other have on internal state within your service, and then force them to orchestrate in order to handle this.

Pushing this responsibility onto your clients is going to make things much more complex in the long run. Ideally clients should be able to call your service in as straightforward manner as possible, without having to know about any other clients who may be using the service. At most clients should be expected to retry if their call was unsuccessful.

Normally you would handle these situations by using locking - the clients could all commit changes simultaneously and all but one will have to retry based on some exception raised or specific response sent back (perhaps including the updated ClientInformation object), depending on how you handle it.

If you absolutely have to implement this notifications stuff, then you could look at using the WCF [duplex bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding.aspx), whereby your service exposes a callback contract which allow clients to register a handler for notification which can be used to send notifications to all clients on a different channel to the one the request was made on. These however, are complex at best to set up and do not scale particularly well.

**EDIT**

In response to your comment, the other half of your question was about sharing state across load balanced service endpoints.

Load balancing wcf is just like load balancing websites - if you need to share state across them you must configure some backing data store which all services have access to.

In your case the obvious place would be the database. You just need to make sure that concurrency/deadlock related problems are caught and handled in your service code (using something like NHibernate to persist the data can help with this). I just don't see that you have a real problem here.

Comment: thats ok for client-service update. but what about service-service update ? I dont see how different wcf instances can communicate and update state in your answer. please let me know